# extracting information from json file (Ekahau)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I'm at my first Python project and want to extract information from Ekahau (Wireless Tool) which stores all information in json format, when extracted.
My initial idea was reading all lines from the file, separating at the ':' and storing the first part as a key and the second part as value in a dictionary (so far no problem).

My issue is building the loop to store the information of the first AP to one dictionary and as soon as the next keys duplicate (beginning with location), write the values to a second dictionary.

Is this even the best way to store this information or am I missing another option ?
I would like to stick to a generic code as this should expand to other files with similar structure too.

This is the file structure:

```
{
  "accessPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "floorPlanId": "0f422470-9c8f-41d7-a51f-a19dcd1208cc",
        "coord": {
          "x": 815.4422419685577,
          "y": 636.5659603554341
        }
      },
      "name": "WarehouseAP-4",
      "mine": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "userDefinedPosition": true,
      "noteIds": [],
      "vendor": "Aruba",
      "model": "AP-574 + ANT-2x2-2314 + ANT-4x4-5314",
      "tags": [],
      "id": "f27feef1-3800-4853-a0fe-21bc1da00d2f",
      "status": "CREATED"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "floorPlanId": "0f422470-9c8f-41d7-a51f-a19dcd1208cc",
        "coord": {
          "x": 2710.3321941216677,
          "y": 981.6322624743677
        }
      },
      "name": "WarehouseAP-3",
      "mine": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "userDefinedPosition": true,
      "noteIds": [],
      "vendor": "Aruba",
      "model": "AP-574 + ANT-2x2-2314 + ANT-4x4-5314",
      "tags": [],
      "id": "535d8800-b264-4737-a4ba-1c69c518ad06",
      "status": "CREATED"
    },
```

This is my new code:

```
        extension = '.json'
        for file_name in all_json_files:  # loop for all json files
            if file_name.endswith(extension):  # check for extension
                json_file_path = temp_files + '/' + file_name
                with open(json_file_path, 'r') as file:
                    data = json.load(file)
```

Original Code:

```
        for file_name in all_json_files:  # loop for all json files
            if file_name.endswith(extension):  
                category = file_name[:-5]      
                json_file_path = temp_files + '/' + file_name
                open_file = open(json_file_path, 'r')
                skip_lines = 2  # amount of lines to skip
                current_line = 0    # reset current_line in each file
                list_of_keys = []  # leere list_of_keys für jede neue category/file
                list_of_values = []

                for lines in open_file:  # loop for each line in the json file
                    lines.strip('{')
                    lines.strip('}')
                    if current_line >= skip_lines and len(lines.split(':')) > 1:  
                        line_content = lines.split(':')  
                        key = line_content[0].strip() 
                        value = line_content[1].strip()  
                        value = value[:-1]  # remove comma at end of line
                        if key not in list_of_keys and value != '':
                            list_of_keys.append(key)
                            if value not in list_of_values:
                                list_of_values.append(value)
                            # for key, value in zip(list_of_keys, list_of_values):   # create database
                            #     database[key] = value
                    current_line += 1
                open_file.close()
```

I was expecting a dictionary for each file, where an inner dictionary includes the information about each item in it so I can use the information about to export and further calculation.

Something like this if useful for my use:

```
accessPoints = {
    'AP001': {'floorPlanId':'', 'name':'Measured-AP-02:f5', 'mine':'true'},
    'AP002': {'floorPlanId':'Warehouse', 'name':'Measured-AP-cc:f8', 'mine':'true'}
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `json.load()` to parse the file?

Comment: damn, thanks, didn't think about this in first step, just tested it and it returns also the structure of the file, might make me my life easier, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A commenter already noted as much, but parsing the json manually is the hard way. Just use `json.load()` and you can interact with the data in a dictionary format (which is your goal).

As an aside - should you choose to loop through the dictionary make sure to use 
 `for key, item in dict.items()` 
or you will only get the keys without the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with the json.load it reduces my code and complexity a lot! I added the new code in the post.
and thanks for the hint about the loop, awesome